# Highlighting JavaScript's dictionary keys in Sublime text

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, associative-array, sublimetext, sublimetext3

is it possible to get a specific syntax highlight of the keys of the associative arrays written in JavaScript with Sublime text?

The following screenshot will illustrate the problem (using Cobalt theme):

[image: object keys do not have dedicated color]

As you can see, the syntax highlighting of that piece of code is very poor.
I would like to get a dedicated color of the object's keys. Is this possible?

Syntax highlighting of setting the fields of an object by dot notation is also unsatisfactory:

[image]

Even in that case the syntax highlighting is dramatically plain: the object, the member field and the rvalue all have the same color.

I tried to edit the XML of the theme, but could not find if the keys are actually identified. What about some regex-based syntax highlight? Is this available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`JavaScriptNext - ES6 Syntax`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScriptNext%20-%20ES6%20Syntax) language definition, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). It has many more scopes than the JavaScript syntax that ships with Sublime, allowing for much finer-grained control of syntax highlighting. Below is your code snippet with JSN applied (the color scheme is [Neon](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme)):

[image]

In the `query` array, the full scope for the key is `constant.other.object.key.js string.unquoted.label.js`, while the scope for the value is `variable.other.readwrite.js` (both are obviously `source.js` as well). As for the `exports` lines, `exports` is `support.keyword.node.js`, the `.add` and `.get` properties are `meta.property.js variable.other.property.js`, and the values are again `variable.other.readwrite.js`.

If you're going to be doing any color scheme customization, there are two tools I highly recommend. The first is [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways), which can be toggled to always show the current scope under the cursor in the status bar. The other is facelessuser's [`ColorSchemeEditor`](https://github.com/facelessuser/ColorSchemeEditor), which provides a GUI for editing `.tmTheme` files. You should be able to install it (the binary will be downloaded automatically) by going to your `Packages` folder on the command line (the folder opened by selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`) and running the following:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/facelessuser/ColorSchemeEditor.git ColorSchemeEditor
```

Restart Sublime, and at some point it will prompt you to download the binary for your platform. If you want to build it from source, or if the other way doesn't work, I've written up a [guide here](http://mattdmo.com/guide-to-installing-colorschemeeditor-for-sublime-text-3/).

Good luck!

Comment: This does not work for me, I'm using the ColorSchemeEditor, when I do click on the element (the key "segment_name" in this case), it shows me the corresponding entry the xml fil: "<string>source.js constant.other.object.key.js string.unquoted.label.js</string>" however, when I try to edit the foreground color in this entry, it does not change the source code color.

Comment: @Øyvind You didn't follow my instructions. Someone else made a package called ColorSchemeEditor, which basically just shows you the XML of the color scheme's `.tmTheme` file. If you have an issue with it, I'd suggest contacting the package's author. Theoretically, you should be able to edit the raw XML appropriately, then save the file and it will apply either immediately or after restarting Sublime.

Comment: I wrote a new question, which better explains my problem, you can have a look at it here if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233738/sublime-text-3-changing-edit-color-scheme-values